# HTML Interview Question

Tags: html, xhtml

Well I got this question in an interview test.Give two reasons why the page might take longer to download than necessary with this image.

`< IMG src="somethin.gif" width=10 height=10 border=0 >`

Well I came up with 3 instead of 2 reasons Xhtml validation problems,image resizing and unnecessary border=0.So what is wrong in here?
.

Comment: The most obvious reason would be that the image itself would need to be downloaded which will add to page loading times. :) And the server might be sending headers which prevent the browser from caching the image, so the image may need to be downloaded every single time the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 9):

Validation problems don't increase download times (and, aside from some extra whitespace, it is the only thing stopping it being valid HTML 4.01 Transitional is the missing alt attribute).

The things that could increase download times are:

- The image **might** be more than 10x10 and have to be scaled down
- Presentational attributes are used instead of cache-friendly CSS (which isn't going to be significant as a one-off)

Images which are inside links have a border by default, so border=0 might not be as "unnecessary" as you think (although it is still better handled with CSS).

Answer (score 3):

There is a space at either end. That's 2 unnecessary bytes to download ;)

Answer (score 1):

`something.gif` might not actually be pointing to a static picture on the filesystem.

`something.gif` might:

- Might Redirect
- Produce non 200 response codes
- Dynamically Created
- Call a server side script(eg [WebBug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug))

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64, {insert base64 image here} >
```

Reduces the download time by about one round trip time. Since it's quite small, 10 by 10,  the overhead of base64 is not significant, I think..

Answer (score 0):

Image used in the code is having big size, that's why it is taking more time to display or download.

Answer (score -2):

The image is using relative path and may not be downloaded at all especially when viewed in an email client.